# I want to use jooq on a server where the DB environment is dynamic

Tags: spring, gradle, jooq

I want to use jooq on a server where the DB environment is dynamic.

I want to use jooq in spring boot 2 gradle environment.
But there is a problem.
The build.gradle file requires hard-coded DB information but is available.
Can I create only JClass like QClass in QueryDSL?

I am in the server's external environment
Creates a dynamic DataSource such as ClassName, UserName, Password, and URL.
Hard-coded jooq can not be used.

## In jooq

```
jooq{
    version = '3.11.2'
    sample(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            url = 'jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/sample'
            user = 'some_user'
            password = 'secret'
....
```

===========
The jdbc connection information should be hard-coded as shown.
But I want a dynamic jooq setting based on the external server settings.
Generally, a dynamic DataSource generation method is already in use.

Help!
I'm sorry I did not speak English.

Comment: You could always use programmatic code generation configuration as documented in the manual: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic, https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle but that would probably prevent using a bunch of useful Gradle build features...

Answer (score 0):

You can build datasource in your configuration class instead of having hardcoded values in application.yml. Something like this:

```
@Bean
private DataSource buildDataSource() {
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("dataSource.url")+ "_somevalue");
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("dataSource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("dataSource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

so you can define datasource url,username,password using some logic.

Comment: In jooq
===========
jooq {
   version = '3.11.2'
   sample (sourceSets.main) {
     jdbc {
       driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
       url = 'jdbc: postgresql: // localhost: 5432 / sample'
       user = 'some_user'
       password = 'secret'
......
===========
The jdbc connection information should be hard-coded as shown.

But I want a dynamic jooq setting based on the external server settings.
Generally, a dynamic DataSource generation method is already in use.